# Customize lazy loading in hibernate

Tags: hibernate, jpa

In my application I am using lazy loading.

My requirement is such that I want to retrieve collection only when a certain annotation(user defined) is present on them.

For this I wrote a  hibernate listener and when I don't find that annotation on collection I set them as `NULL` in `DO`, otherwise hibernate itself will fall through this condition and will retrieve the collection.

But whats happening in the end is, if I set collection as `null`, all related entities are cleared in the DATABASE. 
For e.g.: a `customer` is having set of `orders`. I found there is no annotation ,so the if block will execute and will set `customerDO.setOrders(NULL)`.

My transaction is read only then why update is fired. I am also using spring.
Is there any other way to achieve my requirement ?

I thought about detaching entity also but I don't have access to entity manager and upper layer is not giving access to entity manager.

Comment: Why don't you simply avoid loading the collection, instead of setting it to null? Regarding the read-only-ness of the transaction, [read the doc](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Transactional.html#readOnly%28%29).

Comment: if I dont set it as null then hibernate will call its getter method and collection will be loaded

Comment: Hibernate doesn't call getters. If it did, there would be no lazy-loading anymore. You're calling getters.

Comment: I am  not calling getter. In this listener, when I check for a condition if annotation is present, then set that collection as null. If I don't set it as null, it is fetched. But if I set it as null, it is updated in DB too.